# grid view and adapter not working in android

Tags: android, gridview

i am creating simple app that contains images in an adapter
it works fine in emulator but not on phone

grid and adapter, showing me an error
i have spent 3 days to find the error in google

**gridAdapter**

```
public class Grid_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Integer[] image_grid;
    String[] info;
    private String[] disc;
    private Context c;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;


    Grid_Adapter(Application applicationContext, Integer[] image_grid, String[] info, String[] disc) {
        this.c = applicationContext;
        this.image_grid = image_grid;
        this.info = info;
        this.disc = disc;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return image_grid.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return image_grid[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressLint({"ViewHolder", "InflateParams"})
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.c);

        if (view == null)

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
        ImageView image_g = view.findViewById(R.id.image_grid);
        image_g.setImageResource(image_grid[position]);
        TextView tv = view.findViewById(R.id.txthint);
        tv.setText(info[position]);
        TextView tv2 = view.findViewById(R.id.txthint2);
        tv2.setText(disc[position]);

        return view;
    }
}
```

**gridActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_grid_activities1);
        gridView=findViewById(R.id.gridview);

        Grid_Adapter gridAdapter=new Grid_Adapter(getApplication(),image_grid,info,disc);
        gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View view,int position,long id){
        Intent intent=new Intent(Grid_activities1.this,Image_show.class);
        intent.putExtra("images",image_grid[position]);
        intent.putExtra("text",info[position]);
        intent.putExtra("text2",disc[position]);

        startActivity(intent);
        }
        });


        }
```

**error**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main > Process: com.activities.children, PID: 1040 > java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:    Failed to allocate a 44800012 byte allocation with 12576840 free    bytes and 11MB until OOM > at    dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method) > at    android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method) > at    android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:856) >    at    android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:675)
>   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:2228)
>   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4215)
>   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4089) > at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:2005) > at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1987) >    at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:464) > at    android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:827) > at    android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:434) > at    com.activities.children.Grid_Adapter.getView(Grid_Adapter.java:61) >    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2929) > at    android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1463) > at    android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:366) > at    android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:307) > at    android.widget.GridView.fillFromTop(GridView.java:442) > at    android.widget.GridView.layoutChildren(GridView.java:1291) > at    android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2723) > at    android.view.View.layout(View.java:17938) > at    android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812) > at    android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1742) >    at    android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1731)
>   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1496) > at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17938) > at    android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812) > at    android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344) > at    android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281) > at    android.view.View.layout(View.java:17938) > at    android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812) > at    android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1742) >    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
>   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494) > at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17938) > at    android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812) > at    android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344) > at    android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281) > at    android.view.View.layout(View.java:17938) > at    android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812) > at    android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1742) >    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
>   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494) > at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17938) > at    android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812) > at    android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344) > at    android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281) > at    com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3193)
>   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17938) > at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812) > at    android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2666) > at    android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2367) >    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1437) > at    android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7397)
>   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:920)
>   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:695) > at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631) > at    android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:906)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) > at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) > at    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) > at android.app.Acti

Comment: you dont have enough space in your device.Clear up some space or use another device to test

Comment: how many images are in your arrray

Comment: this may be occurring due to space problem try with low quality images.

Comment: try to replace your image with low quality,i think your pbm got resolve

Comment: @Milan Pansuriya  there are 100 images jpg  extension

Comment: @ Kevin Kurien The problem occurred after i upload the app on the App Store
There were errors on Android version 6-7

Comment: @safaa that's why your app is crash for this you can upload images to the server and retrieve from server and display in to your app

Comment: @safaa can you share your playstore link

Comment: Why it works in android 8 and 9 without error

Comment: probably because devices for android 8 and 9 have more memory than older android versions